# How can i pass a parameter containing a slash in Chocolatey?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I'm trying to install a package that needs a password passed to the install script.

```
choco install <mypackage> -d -s <mysource> -y --params "/username:<username> /password:<password>"
```

If `<username>` or `<password>` contains a forward slash chocolatey splits the parameter and only uses the part up to the first slash.

How can i pass a parameter containing one or more slashes without Chocolatey interpreting them as separator for the parameter list?

**Edit:**

chocolateyinstall.ps1

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; # stop on all errors

$pp = Get-PackageParameters

$username = $pp['username']
$password = $pp['password']
Write-Host ("Credentials Username '{0}'" -f $username)
Write-Host ("Credentials Password '{0}'" -f $password)

#[do install stuff]
```

Powershell command

```
choco install <packagename> v1.2.123.4 -d -s C:\\Users\\<foo>\\Desktop\\ -y --params "'/username:value' '/password:val/ue'"
```

Output

```
Running Get-PackageParameters
Parsing $env:ChocolateyPackageParameters and $env:ChocolateyPackageParametersSensitive for parameters
Adding package param 'username'='value' ''
Adding package param 'password'='val'
Adding package param 'ue'='True'
Credentials Username 'value' ''
Credentials Password 'val'
```

Comment: Do single quotes make a difference? `--params '/username:<username> /password:<password>'`

Comment: @JamesC. No, it splits the parameter at the same point. When Using double quotes and putting single quotes around the password it already fails before running the installscript. (Misinterpreting a '+' in the Password as an operator)

Comment: Oh so it's an internal issue with Chocolatey, best raise it with them https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a bit of documentation on using Package Parameters on the website here:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-parse-package-parameters-argument

If you follow through some of the code on there, you will end up with something like this:

```
$pp = Get-PackageParameters

Write-Host $pp['LICENSE']
```

If you then call this with the following:

```
choco install <pkg_id> --params "'/LICENSE:val/ue'"
```

You will see that it correctly outputs

`val/ue`

which is what I think you are after.

**NOTE:** That article, and this answer assume that you are using Chocolatey 0.10.8.

**NOTE:** This further assumes that you are **NOT** using the chocolatey-core.extension package.  The way that it handles the parsing of parameters is slightly different to how the built in function does it.

Expanding this for two parameters:

```
$pp = Get-PackageParameters

Write-Host $pp['LICENSE']

Write-Host $pp['PASSWORD']
```

And calling with this:

```
choco install <pkg_id> --params "'/LICENSE:val/ue' '/PASSWORD:value/1'"
```

Should output

`val/ue`

and then

`value/1`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried it with the code from your post and the output was "val" for the License and "value" for the password.

Comment: What version of Chocolatey are you using? I tested this code before posting, and I can confirm it does indeed work.

Comment: This is weird. I'm using version 0.10.8.

Comment: Obvious question first... Are you copy/pasting the examples above?  If not, are you sure you are including both the `"` and the `'`.  Can you post, in a gist perhaps, an example of something that isn't working for you?

Comment: Yes, i copy/pasted it. And I added an example to the OP.

Comment: I have just re-ran your example that you added and this is the output that I get:  Credentials Username 'value'', and then: Credentials Password 'val/ue'.  Are you perhaps taking a dependency on the chocolatey.coreextension, or anything like that?

Comment: That might be the case, i will check as soon as possible.

Comment: After doing "choco upgrade chocolatey-core.extension" the test gives the expected output, so this is the right answer.  Thank you!